# Android GPS toggle on/off programmatically

Tags: android

How can I toggle the GPS Satellite on and off (the icon), I am not looking for this one

```
// automatic turn off the gps
public void turnGPSOff()
{
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
    if (provider.contains("gps")) // if gps is enabled
    { 
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
        this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

This one only disable the GPS satellite searching but not toggle off the GPS icon

Comment: Why you want to turn off the gps as you are saying the code disable the gps for you

Comment: Apologize for not clear regarding the problem, what I want is code like close wifi WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); can actually toggle off the wifi toggle button, but for GPS , it only allow to off the GPS satellite searching but not the GPS toggle button on the notification drawer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon is controlled by whether any app is actively using GPS (e.g., has called `requestLocationUpdates()` for `GPS_PROVIDER`). You are welcome to control your app's use of GPS, but you otherwise have no means of affecting that icon from an app.

Comment: I am apologize that my problem is not clear enough, I should say is the GPS toggle button is not off, I trying to get a code that can toggle off the GPS on the notification drawer like close the wifi WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    wifi.setWifiEnabled(false); , the code actually work on toggle off the WIFI toggle button

Comment: @Andrew: That is enabling or disabling GPS, which Android apps also cannot do.

Comment: Well, I think the part cant continue and it reach limit, you solve my doubt

Answer (score -1):

**Try this its work for me yesterday**

```
 //Enable GPS
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
 intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
 sendBroadcast(intent);
//Disable GPS
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
 intent.putExtra("enabled", false);
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

reference link    [Answer](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/613512/How-to-start-GPS-ON-and-OFF-programatically-in-And)

Comment: I did try this code, but the GPS toggle button on Notification Drawer doesn't off......